# 802.11 how do i find out if packet is encrypted with WEP or WPA

Tags: ieee-802.11

i am playing with the 802.11 header, trying to figure out the encryption type of incoming 0x08(DATA) packets.

[image: 802.11 Header]

1) I capture the 0x08 type packet (DATA).

2) I find out that a WEP bit is set (2nd byte of Frame Control, 7th BIT).

3) Now i need to figure out, if this is a WEP encrypted or WPA encrypted packet, how do i find out?

Packet:

> 08 42 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 34 7A 60 72 A7 9A 80 86 F2 24 0C 2F 80 A5 C0 01 00 60 59 ED 78 D9 3E D4 59 43 01 00 82 00 80 A5 80 86 F2 24 0C 2F 6C 03 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 00 AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC 02 0C 00 32 04 0C 12 18 60 0B 05 01 00 41 00 00 2D 1A BC 19 1B FF FF 00 01 00 19 01 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

And here are the bits of first 2 bytes of Frame Control:

> 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0

It looks like **WEP** bit is set both for **WEP** and **WPA** packets am i correct?

Thanks for any input into this.

Comment: The first two bytes are `08 42`, but you converted incorrectly to `0010 0000 0100 0010`, which is `20 42`.

Comment: yes, sorry - my bad, will edit.

Comment: Now, you have it as `80 42`, not `08 42`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there was no interest in this so i had to find it out myself.
Here's the answer from a great book.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Book: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/80211-wireless-networks/0596100523/ch04.html#

Comment: Well that was a helpful answer. pretty much the only result on google. Thanks !